# Paste only once when combing character in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to combine the characters only once. Below is the example

```
> dfew <- data.frame(x=c("John S", "Carl", "Katy Smith", "J P Morgan Stanley")) 
> paste("list(",dfew$x,")", collapse = ",")
[1] "list( John S ),list( Carl ),list( Katy Smith ),list( J P Morgan Stanley )"
```

The below code is giving a perfect result

```
sub_list <- paste0('list( ',paste0(dfew$x,collapse = ', '),' )')
```

Actual output

```
[1] "list( John S , Carl , Katy Smith , J P Morgan Stanley )"
```

However with the below dataframe, when I follow the same steps, backslashes are returning . Can we avoid them?

```
df
COlA    COlB
1       list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11")
2       list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"), vedd = c("11", "11", "11"))
```

Output that is returing

```
sub_list <- paste0('list( ',paste0(df$COlB,collapse = ', '),' )')
> sub_list
[1] "list( list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\"), list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\")) )"
```

Can we avoid this backslashes?

Final Expected output

```
> sub_list
[1] "list( list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11"), list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"), vedd = c("11", "11", "11")) )"
```

The reason why I need the expected output is

I perform below operation (I just copy paste the ColB values)

Code 1 below

```
df <- tibble(ID = 1:2, 
             ColB = list(list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11"), list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"), vedd = c("11", "11", "11"))))
```

The output of code 1 is below (That is perfect)

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID ColB            
  <int> <list>          
1     1 <named list [3]>
2     2 <named list [3]>
```

But when I get backslashes,I cannot copy paste ColB values. If I do, I do not get output

Code2

```
df <- tibble(ID = 1:2, 
             ColB = list( list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\"), list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\")))
```

There is an error when I perform Code 2

```
Error: unexpected input in:
"df <- tibble(ID = 1:2, 
             ColB = list( list(ved = \"
```

Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: Do you have a `list` column with `ColB`?  Can you updated with the `dput` of the 'df' so that the structure would be clear

Comment: ````class(df$COLB)```` is a character. But it has list() all over the rows as shown

Comment: if you can update the post with `dput(df)` showed, then it would help in understanding the strcutre along with your expected output.  Also, why do you need to wrap with `list` as a string

Comment: The issue is that when you show `list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11")` it is a `list` element and this is different from `"list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11")"`

Comment: what would you require as expected

Comment: There is a need to wrap list as a string . In later stages of the analysis, I am going to unnest it so only

Comment: Yes, can you show the expected output as well so that it is not that confusing

Comment: Do you need `"list(ved = c(19, 65, 83, 2), ved_name = c(No, At, Re, Rum), vedd = c(11, 11, 11, 11))"`

Comment: Edited expected output :)

Comment: Then, my solution should work `as.character(glue::glue("list({toString(df$COlB)})"))`

Comment: If you need quotes around each of the element, which is not present in your original data, then there is going to be escape character, which is fine.  can you check by printing with `cat`

Comment: @Akrun. Sorry my bad. The structure is here ````structure(list(COlA = c(1, 2), COlB = c("list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\")", 
"list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\"))"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))````. There is a double quotes. I really what is happening here. Basically, I need the double quotes as shown in expected output :) Not sure how to get it

Comment: You get the double quotes as well, just look at `cat(as.character(glue::glue("list({toString(df$COlB)})")))`

Comment: You don't need to remove the double quotes, the backslash is just for escaping, nothing to worry about

Comment: @Akrun, I have explained why there is a need. My end goal is to make a tibble out of it. I have to copy paste the output I get. If I get backslashes, I cannot copy and paste since it gives me an error. Now makes sense?

Comment: can u show where it generate error. seems like you need to evaluate the expression'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `with` with `paste`

```
 with(dfew, paste0("list(", toString(x), ")"))
 #[1] "list(John S, Carl, Katy Smith, J P Morgan Stanley)"
```

---

Or using `glue`

```
as.character(glue::glue("list({toString(dfew$x)})"))
#[1] "list(John S, Carl, Katy Smith, J P Morgan Stanley)"
```

---

If the actual string have `"` and wants to remove, just use

```
str1 <-  "list( list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\"), list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\")) )"

gsub('"', "", str1)
#[1] "list( list(ved = 19, ved_name = No, vedd = 11), list(ved = c(65, 83, 2), ved_name = c(At, Re, Rum), vedd = c(11, 11, 11)) )"
```

---

Based on the OP's new data

```
cat(as.character(glue::glue("list({toString(df$COlB)})")))
#list(list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11"), list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"), vedd = c("11", "11", "11")))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(COlA = c(1, 2), COlB = c("list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\")", 
"list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\"))"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 3):

The key here is you need to get your string (`dfew$x`) into length 1 (currently it is of length 4). The easiest way to collapse it into length 1 is using `toString`.

You can use `sprintf` to add prefix, postfix characters to the required string.

```
sprintf('list(%s)', toString(dfew$x))
#[1] "list(John S, Carl, Katy Smith, J P Morgan Stanley)"
```

OR with `paste`/`paste0` :

```
paste0('list( ', toString(dfew$x), ' )')
#paste('list( ', toString(dfew$x), ' )')
```

Comment: Rather than using `paste0` with redundant spaces, why not use `paste` without those spaces?

Answer (score 0):

It is also valid combining `paste()` in this way:

```
#Code
paste0('list( ',paste0(dfew$x,collapse = ', '),' )')
```

Output:

```
[1] "list( John S, Carl, Katy Smith, J P Morgan Stanley )"
```

Given that some elements from string need to be removed, here the code:

```
#Data
x1 <- "list( list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\"), list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\")) )"
```

Code:

```
#Code
gsub("\"","",x1)
```

Output:

```
[1] "list( list(ved = 19, ved_name = No, vedd = 11), list(ved = c(65, 83, 2), ved_name = c(At, Re, Rum), vedd = c(11, 11, 11)) )"
```